# HTML5 player play button does not show

Tags: html5-video

i have searched for a while trying to solve this problem. I need the HTML 5 player button to show, (not the controls at the bottom they are showing) but the big play button that shows by default before the play button is clicked. At the moment all it shows is a black box over the video without the play button. In FF it is there, in Safari, IE and Chrome it is not there. I have tried with and without the poster, with and without the controls and preload attribute, just at a loss. Code below, any help is appreciated so thanks in advance

```
   <video poster="media/jw_allvideos/SafeTrench.jpg" preload="auto" controls="controls" width="300" height="auto">
    <source src="media/jw_allvideos/SafeTrench.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="media/jw_allvideos/SafeTrench.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

  Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple workaround: include the play button in your poster and add onclick.

```
  <video id="video" controls poster="play.jpg" onclick="this.play();">
    <source src="video.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.ogv"  type="video/ogg">
  </video>
```

But the button will not show up again when you pause the video.

Comment: problem is i will have to be exact because it shows in FF and there is no way to turn off the big play button, may cause issues when the browser is resized, ill give it a go and see what happens, thanks for your comment